# Local properties to Global properties of compact spaces

Tags: general-topology

> Context: moving local properties to global properties of compact spaces.
>
> If $X$ has this property locally, i.e, every point has a neighborhood has the property $P$  then $X$ itself has the property. In fact each such open neighborhood forms a open cover of $X$ .... ; but choosing $x_i$ appropriately.
>
> *Klaus Janich Topology*

I am wondering, there can be a $x \in X$ but every open set $O \neq X$ imply $x \notin O$ then the only open cover of $X$ itself is $\{X\}$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is equipped with anything but the trivial topology then $\{X\}$ is not the only open cover of $X$.  But since $X$ is the only open set about $x$ any open cover of $X$ must contain $X$.